# How to write Arabic in Genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, genymotion

I am using Android Studio & using Genymotion as my mobile emulator. Genymotion works fine until I trying to write Arabic characters through switching keyboard & through copy/paste, however my trials failed where the emulator keeps hanging through throwing errors.

How to write Arabic in Genymotion emulator?

Answer (score 3):

- go to "menu"
- go to "settings"
- go to "Language & input"
- go to "Android Keyboard(AOSP)"
- go to "Languages"
- turn off "Use system language"
- in "Active input methods" you can active any keyboards that you need.

Hope it can help you ...

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion is not an emulator, it is a virtualization engine.
You may want to look at the various UTF encoding settings to ensure internationalization is region compatible.

Comment: Hello Dominic, First let me thank you for answering my question however do you know how to set UTF encoding in Genymotion?