# How to make the text field accept other language flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

### The Problem

When I try to type Arabic it just don't show. I tried to look for answer but most what I found how to make the whole app in different language.

### Code

```
                  Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Container(
                          width: width-80,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            //for disable for the done button
                            controller: titleControl,

                            onChanged: (val) {
                              /*change the val of title*/
                              setState(() {
                                title = val;
                              });
                            },

                            /*validation*/
                            validator: (val) {
                              if (val!.isEmpty) {
                                return "Title should not be empty";
                              }
                              if (val.length >= 35) {
                                return "Create a shorter title under 36 characters.";
                              }
                              if ((val.contains("*") ||
                                  val.contains("\\")||
                                  val.contains("%") ||
                                  val.contains("~") ||
                                  val.contains("^") ||
                                  val.contains("+") ||
                                  val.contains("=") ||
                                  val.contains("{") ||
                                  val.contains("[") ||
                                  val.contains("}") ||
                                  val.contains("]") ||
                                  val.contains(":") ||
                                  val.contains(";") ||
                                  val.contains("\\")||
                                  val.contains("<") ||
                                  val.contains(">") )) {
                                return "Title should not contain symbol. Only ',?!_-&@#.";
                              }
                              return null;
                            },

                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              /*background color*/
                              fillColor: Palette.lightgrey,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 10),

                              /*hint*/
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: "Title",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Palette.grey,
                                height: 2.0,),

                              /*Border*/
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Palette.midgrey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Palette.midgrey,
                                  width: 2.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      /*end of title*/
```

### What I tried

I follow video to make the whole app in another language.
In `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0

#...

flutter:
  generate: true
```

In the `main`:

```
supportedLocales: L10n.all,
```

Created L10n that look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class L10n {
  static final all = [
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('ar'),
    const Locale('hi'),
    const Locale('es'),
    const Locale('de'),
  ];
}
```

Then I realize this was not my issues I don't want to make the whole app in another language I just want to make the text filed accept Arabic.

Comment: It will work on a physical device but in the emulator you have to do  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356502/7814781)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [translator](https://pub.dev/packages/translator) pachege

```
final translator = GoogleTranslator();

final input = "Здравствуйте. Ты в порядке?";

translator.translate(input, from: 'ru', to: 'en').then(print);
// prints Hello. Are you okay?

var translation = await translator.translate("Dart is very cool!", to: 
   'pl');
print(translation);
// prints Dart jest bardzo fajny!

print(await "example".translate(to: 'pt'));
```